# Plugging a kitchen sprayer that has a quick-connect fastener?

Tags: kitchens, faucet, sink, dishwasher

TL;DR: Is there an easy way to properly plug a kitchen faucet sprayer when the sprayer uses a quick-connect instead of a threaded connection? Simply cutting the hose and plugging it isn't an option.

Full story: My wife and I currently rent our house, and we only have a sink with a sprayer in the kitchen, no dishwasher or in-sink garbage disposal. She managed to find a great deal on a portable dishwasher ($50 for a barely-used one that would have retailed for around $300), and snapped it up. We stashed it in the garage until I could get the time to hook it up.

Upon further research (hindsight is always 20/20), I found that hooking up a portable to a faucet with a sprayer can potentially cause the sprayer to blow. The obvious solution was to remove the sprayer and cap the feed to the sprayer hose. I figured it would be no big deal, as the guides I found online basically showed unscrewing the hose and capping it with a 3/8" brass cap, and we could just stash the sprayer under the sink & put it back when we move out. Easy-peasy, right? I popped over to the hardware store and got a cap, tape, and a plug for the sprayer hole in the sink, figuring that the faucet would have standard fittings.

Wrong again. Upon getting under the sink, I found that the faucet uses a quick-connect sprayer hose, rather than a standard threaded connection. The thing uses a Peerless/Delta RP54807 sprayer kit. This obviously torpedoed my plan to just cap the thing and be done with it, because there were no threads to screw anything on to.

This brings me to my question: Is there an easy, non-permanent way to remove the sprayer and cap that quick-connect barb, so we can hook up the dishwasher? If not, I'll happily just swap the faucet for one with standard connections, but I'd really rather not do that if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home Depot carries caps for most quick connects. Go to the store and look at the RP40301 (cap for round) or the RP60295 (cap for square quick connect). Both are made for Delta to convert faucets from "with sprayer" to "without sprayer". These Delta numbers will work at other stores, too.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The RP60294 was exactly what I was looking for, given my faucet model. Unfortunately, it was unavailable locally (no-go at both Home Depot and Menards), but I was able to find it online. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Me i took the top off and removed the diverter, Squeezed silicon into the hole and put put a brass screw with threads smaller than the hole and a head a tiny bit bigger.  cleaned up excess silicon with long hemostats after it dried.  When i wanted it out i just pushed a dowel rod thru the bottom of the hole and pushed the screw and silicon out.  Put the diverter back in and hooked up a sprayer.    The things you do when you have to get inventive.  a rubber piece silicone down would do the same just don't cover the water inlets.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] your answer to make it more readable. It's very hard to envision what you're trying to say, for example "Squeezed silicon into the hole and put put a brass screw with threads smaller than the hole and a head a tiny bit bigger". Maybe it's just me, but that's clear as mud.